# akku powered esp8266 led stripe system

Tags: esp8266, led

I want to create a system to control a led stripe with an esp8266, it would be easy if I had a socket for the power supply, 
but it has to be mobile so I need a akku for it

Could you guys please give me some tips for my idea :)

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: And what software problem is this supposed to be?

Comment: Without energy the software will not work 

Comment: This doesn't make the problem about software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for a development board that has the ESP as well as the battery integrated already, like the [Adafruit Feather HUZZAH with ESP8266 WiFi](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821). They also sell the compatible LiPo batteries with it.

Comment: Thank you very much i think that is a really good idea :)

Comment: Happy to help Benjamin! Be sure to upvote and accept ;)